# Get scan codes in octal format

Tags: bash, zsh, conversion, key-mapping

Using `showkey -s` I can get the scancode of a key as a hex-number. How can I get it directly as an octal number?

Answer (score 1):

`showkey` has no switch for that, but you can always pipe the output to another program to do the conversion.

With `zsh` you can do it like this:

```
stdbuf -oL showkey -s | while read line
do
  if [[ "$line" =~ '^0x' ]]
  then
    for code in ${(z)line}
    do
      printf "0%o " $code
    done
    echo
  else
    echo $line
  fi
done
```

`stdbuf` is part of the *GNU coreutils* and can be used to modify buffering operations on the standard streams. Called with `-oL` it adjusts *stdout* to be line buffered. This has to be done in order for the output of `showkey -s` to be passed immediatelly through the pipe line by line. Otherwise the output would only be passed when the buffer is full (usually several kB) or the program exits.

The output is piped to a `while`-loop, which reads each line into the variable `line` until the pipe closes. If `line` starts with `0x` (matches regex '^0x') each hex number (`${(z)param}` splits a line into words like the zsh would split a command line) is converted to octal (Actually the hex number is implicitly converted to decimal by the shell and than formatted as octal by `printf`). If `line` does not start with `0x` print it as is.

---

You could also use `perl`:

```
stdbuf -oL showkey -s | perl -e '
  while(<STDIN>){
    if(/^0x/){ 
      printf "0%o ", hex($_) for split; 
      print $/;
    } else { 
      print 
    }
  }'
```

The same principle applies.

Answer (score -1):

When you run this in "ascii mode" it prints the octal representation of the key.

#### Example

```
$ sudo showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

a    97 0141 0x61
b    98 0142 0x62
c    99 0143 0x63
d   100 0144 0x64
e   101 0145 0x65
f   102 0146 0x66
g   103 0147 0x67
1    49 0061 0x31
2    50 0062 0x32
3    51 0063 0x33
^D    4 0004 0x04
```

The 3rd column is the octal code.

*excerpt from the `showkey` man page*

> When in `ascii' dump mode, showkey prints to the standard output the decimal, octal, and hexadecimal value(s) of the  key pressed, according to he present keymap.

Comment: This gives the `ascii`-code but not the scan code. From the showkey man-page: `showkey  prints  to  standard output either the scan codes or the keycode or the
       ascii code of each key pressed.`